# Функция разности для двух дат

Tags: sql, oracle

Не понимаю, в чём ошибка.

```
create or replace FUNCTION  Living (password VARCHAR2, dateinc DATE)
RETURN DATE
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE RES DATE
SET RES = (SELECT TRUNC(DATEOUT) - TRUNC(DATEIN) as Living  
       FROM CUSTOMERS
       WHERE password = Password)
RETURN (RES)
END Living;
```

Подчеркивает красным `RES` там, где `Set`

Comment: Извините, я не знаю кто или что у вас красным подчеркивает, оно точно не право. Надо зачеркнуть почти всё  жирным красным и начать всё сначала. Откуда вы это взяли?

Answer (score 1):

Сложно как-то у вас написана функция. Попробуйте вот это:

```
create or replace function Living(p_password varchar2, p_dateinc date)
  return date
is
  l_living date;
begin
  SELECT TRUNC(c.DATEOUT) - TRUNC(p_dateinc)
   into l_living
  FROM CUSTOMERS c
  WHERE c.password = p_password;
  return l_living;
exception
  when no_data_found then 
  --обработка если запрос ничего не вернул
    dbms_output.put_line('Ошибка в функции Living- покупатель с паролем отсутствует');
  when too_many_rows then
  --обработка исключения если вернул больше 2х значений
    dbms_output.put_line('Ошибка в функции Living- у 2х покупателей одинаковые пароли');
end Living;
```

Comment: Даже не скомпилируется. Вы проверили перед тем, как опубликовать?

Comment: @0xdb спасибо, поправил.